# Why two intersected paths can't buildcycle in MetaPost?

Tags: metapost

Suppose that I have two path:

```
beginfig(0)
u:=10pt;
vardef randomcirc(expr O, r, w) = 
  save p,i; pair p; numeric i;
    p=O+right*r;
    p for i=1 upto 9: .. (p rotatedaround(O, 36i))+(uniformdeviate w, uniformdeviate w) endfor .. cycle
enddef;
path pat[];
pair p[];
p0:=(0,5u); p3:=(-8u,0);
pat0:=randomcirc(p0,8u,.5u);
pat3:=randomcirc(p3,5u,0.4u);
fill buildcycle(pat0, pat3) withcolor red;
draw pat0; draw pat3;
endfig;
```

why their intersection are not filled with red color?

I think it's due to the precision of MetaPost too low, how to fix it?

Comment: ok, maybe I forget to define `u:=10pt;`

Comment: If I say `pat4=buildcycle(pat0,pat3)` and `show pat4`, I get `(-77.10028,51.76262)..controls (-77.10014,51.76274) and (-77.10033,51.76294)..(-77.10046,51.76282)..controls (-77.1006,51.7627) and (-77.10042,51.7625)..cycle`. I can't say why, but this explains why you don't see the filling.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `plain.mp` implementation of `buildcycle` fails to find the correct overlap between two cyclic paths if the beginning (`point 0`) of one of the paths lies inside the other path. For example:

```
beginfig(3);
  path A, B; picture p[];
  A = fullcircle scaled 2.5cm; 
  B = fullcircle scaled 2cm shifted (1cm,0);

  p1 = image(fill buildcycle(A,B) withcolor .8[blue,white]; drawarrow A; drawarrow B;);

  A := A rotated 180;
  p2 = image(fill buildcycle(A,B) withcolor .8[blue,white]; drawarrow A; drawarrow B;);

  B := B rotatedabout(center B,180);
  p3 = image(fill buildcycle(A,B) withcolor .8[blue,white]; drawarrow A; drawarrow B;);

  A := A rotated 180;
  p4 = image(fill buildcycle(A,B) withcolor .8[blue,white]; drawarrow A; drawarrow B;);

  for i=1 upto 4: draw p[i] shifted (120i,0); label(decimal i, (7mm+120i,0)); endfor
endfig;
```

produces

[image]

In each subfigure, the arrow head is pointing at the beginning of the path.
You can see that `buildcycle` only works in situation 2 where neither `point 0` lies within the other cyclic path.  Note that in situation 4 we get the **union** of the two paths.

Here's a way to correct this fault.  First you need a function to determine whether a given point lies within a cyclic path. Following Sedgewick's *Algorirthms in C*, you can write:

```
% is point "p" inside cyclic path "ring" ?
vardef inside(expr p, ring) = 
  save t, count, test_line;
  count := 0;
  path test_line;
  test_line = p -- (infinity, ypart p);
  for i = 1 upto length ring:
     t := xpart(subpath(i-1,i) of ring intersectiontimes test_line);
     if ((0<=t) and (t<1)): count := count + 1; fi
  endfor
  odd(count)
  enddef;
```

And here is an `overlap` function that replaces `buildcycle` in this special case of two overlapping cyclic paths.

```
vardef front_half primary p = subpath(0, 1/2 length p) of p enddef;
vardef back_half  primary p = subpath(1/2 length p, length p) of p enddef;

% a and b should be cyclic paths...
vardef overlap(expr a, b) = 
  save p, q;
  boolean p, q;
  p = inside(point 0 of a, b);
  q = inside(point 0 of b, a);
  if ((not p) and (not q)): 
    buildcycle(a,b)
  elseif (not p): 
    buildcycle(front_half b, a, back_half b)
  elseif (not q): 
    buildcycle(front_half a, b, back_half a)
  else: 
    buildcycle(front_half a, back_half b, front_half b, back_half a)
  fi
  enddef;
```

The basic idea is that if neither `point 0` is inside the other path, then you just call `buildcycle`, otherwise you split the two cycles up into an appropriate sequence of half cycles.  Replacing `buildcycle` in the above example with `overlap` gives this:

[image]

And replacing `buildcycle` in the OP example with `overlap` gives this:

[image]

which is probably closer to what was wanted in the first place.

Furthermore, if the two cyclic paths are running in *opposite directions* the behaviour of `buildcycle` is different again.  Here's an extended version of the first example; in the second row, the larger path is running backwards:

[image]

To deal with this possibility you can make `overlap` more robust by using the useful `counterclockwise` function (from `plain.mp`) which returns a copy of a cyclic path running counterclockwise.  Here is the improved version of the `overlap` function.

```
vardef overlap(expr a, b) = 
  save p, q, A, B;
  boolean p, q;
  p = not inside(point 0 of a, b);
  q = not inside(point 0 of b, a);
  path A, B;
  A = counterclockwise a;
  B = counterclockwise b;
  if (p and q): 
    buildcycle(A,B)
  elseif p: 
    buildcycle(front_half B, A, back_half B)
  elseif q: 
    buildcycle(front_half A, B, back_half A)
  else: 
    buildcycle(front_half A, back_half B, front_half B, back_half A)
  fi
  enddef;
```

which produces this in my extended example.

[image]

Comment: I've just found an interesting counterexample: say that `a = fullcircle scaled 6cm` and `b = a reflectedabout(origin, right) shifted (0, 4cm)`. Then `buildcycle(a, b)` gives nothing, despite the fact that each starting point is outside the other path. The reason is that the `point 1` and `point 2` defined in fig. 24b of the MetaPost manual are the same in this case. However, `buildcycle(a, reverse b)` works as expected. It seems thus that the turningnumber of the paths should be taken into account.

Comment: @fpast - thanks, I suspect that there are lots of counter examples - in general both cyclic paths should be going in the same direction.

Comment: @fpast see updated solution which should cope with reflected or reversed paths...

Comment: Great! One more thing: `buildcycle` can also fail for non-cyclic paths. For example, when `fullcircle` is replaced by `halfcircle` in my counterexample above). I Would suggest extending your `overlap` macro to that kind of paths, e.g. by replacing arguments `a` and `b` by `a..cycle`, `b..cycle` if they are not cycles, before applying `overlap` upon them.

Answer (score 10):

It works here if I change slightly the definition of `pat3`, making `pat3` start at the "left" (so to speak) of the circle and not at the "right" (to the contrary of `pat0`). For this, I defined another `vardef` macro (`randomcirc_bis`)

```
beginfig(0)
    u:=10pt;
    vardef randomcirc(expr O, r, w) = 
        save p,i; pair p; numeric i;
         p=O+right*r;
        p for i=1 upto 9: .. (p rotatedaround(O, 36i))+(uniformdeviate w, uniformdeviate w)                
        endfor .. cycle
    enddef;
    %
    vardef randomcirc_bis(expr O, r, w) = 
        save p,i; pair p; numeric i;
        p=O+left*r;
        p for i=1 upto 9: .. (p rotatedaround(O, 36i))+(uniformdeviate w, uniformdeviate w)  
        endfor .. cycle
    enddef;
%
    path pat[];
    pair p[];
    p0:=(0,5u); p3:=(-8u,0);
    pat0:=randomcirc(p0,8u,.5u);
    pat3:=randomcirc_bis(p3,5u,0.4u);
    pat4 = buildcycle(pat0, pat3);
    fill pat4 withcolor red;
    draw pat0; draw pat3 dashed evenly;
    %
    dotlabel.ulft("1", pat0 intersectionpoint pat3);
    dotlabel.lrt("2", pat3 intersectionpoint pat0);
    label.rt("aa", point 0 of pat0);
    label.lft("b", point 0 of pat3);
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

In this drawing I tried to reproduce exactly the modus operandi of `buildcycle` as explained in the MetaPost manual, p. 30 (section 9.1, "Building Cycles"). Citation:

> The `buildcycle` macro detects the two intersections labeled 1 and 2 in
>   Figure 24b. Then it constructs the cyclic path shown in bold in the
>   figure by going forward along path aa from intersection 1 to
>   intersection 2 and then forward around the counter-clockwise path b
>   back to intersection 1.

If I understand the macro `intersectionpoint` correctly, point 1 is in fact `aa intersectionpoint b` and it is the *first* intersection that `aa` (`pat0`) encounters with `b` (`pat3`).

Similarly point 2 is `b intersectiopoint aa`, and it is also the *first* intersection that `b` (`pat3`) encounters with `aa` (`pat0`).

To reproduce this scheme it has been necessary to start the path `pat3` at the left. Otherwise the first intersection that `pat3=b` would have met with `pat0=aa` would have been point 1. The two intersection points would have been the same, and in that case `buildcycle` fails.

I hope I have not been too confusing: English is not my native language…

**UPDATE**

I have simplified the code. My new vardef macro `randomcircbis` wasn't necessary. It was enough to replace the line `pat3:=randomcirc(p3,5u,0.4u);`in the original code by `pat3:=randomcirc(p3,-5u,0.4u);`. The resulting figure is the same, of course.

```
beginfig(0)
    u:=10pt;
    vardef randomcirc(expr O, r, w) = 
        save p,i; pair p; numeric i;
         p=O+right*r;
        p for i=1 upto 9: .. (p rotatedaround(O, 36i))+(uniformdeviate w, uniformdeviate w)                
        endfor .. cycle
    enddef;
%
    path pat[];
    pair p[];
    p0:=(0,5u); p3:=(-8u,0);
    pat0:=randomcirc(p0,8u,.5u);
    pat3:=randomcirc(p3,-5u,0.4u);
    pat4 = buildcycle(pat0, pat3);
    fill pat4 withcolor red;
    draw pat0; draw pat3 dashed evenly;
    %
    dotlabel.ulft("1", pat0 intersectionpoint pat3);
    dotlabel.lrt("2", pat3 intersectionpoint pat0);
    label.rt("aa", point 0 of pat0);
    label.lft("b", point 0 of pat3);
endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another implementation of the same idea as in fpast's answer. Instead of starting with a point on the left, you can just rotate the original circle by 180 degrees. (I also simplified the code for randomized circle a bit).

```
\startMPdefinitions
  vardef randomcircle(expr O, r, w, a) = 
    ((fullcircle rotated  a scaled 2r) randomized w shifted O)
  enddef;
\stopMPdefinitions
\starttext

\startMPpage[offset=2mm]
  u:=10pt;
  path pat[];
  pair p[];

  p0:=(0,5u); p3:=(-8u,0);

  pat0 = randomcircle(p0, 8u, 0.4u, 0);
  pat3 = randomcircle(p3, 5u, 0.4u, 180);

  fill buildcycle(pat0, pat3) withcolor red;

  draw pat0;
  draw pat3;

  dotlabel.ulft("1", pat0 intersectionpoint pat3);
  dotlabel.lrt("2", pat3 intersectionpoint pat0);
  label.rt("aa", point 0 of pat0);
  label.lft("b", point 0 of pat3);
\stopMPpage

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Undoubtedly more elegant! :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no automatic way of doing this (i.e., if the centres and radii of the circle change, you may need to rotate the other circle or not rotate any circle at all). I wish Metapost were smart enough to figure all this out on its own.

Comment: Ok, the realy interesting thing is why not to rebuild the `buildcycle` which make it work in any case proivded two path do intersect?

Comment: It is certainly more complicated than it seems. According to the MetaPost manual, `buildcycle` works best with a sequence of more than two paths and if in each pair of consecutive paths, the first path has only one intersection point with the second one. There are here two (closed) paths with two intersections, and at least four feasible cycles could be considered as feasible solutions (the left, the middle — the expected solution —, the right and the outer part). Not mentioning the "degenerated" possibilities like points 1 and 2. Any algorithm would wonder which one is to be chosen, I guess.

Comment: @fpast: I wonder how does Asymptote's `buildcycle` function work? Is it same as Metapost?

Comment: @Aditya: Quoting Asymptote's manual (version 2.23), p. 40: `path buildcycle(... path[] p);`
"This returns the path surrounding a region bounded by a list of two or more consecutively intersecting paths, following the behaviour
of the MetaPost buildcycle command." So I guess it works just the same way.

Comment: @Aditya – you might be interested in my solution below.