# How to draw four squares arranged as in the following figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know how to draw each square separately, but I can't put them together as shown in the figure.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't really need `pics`, but anyway the basic idea is to exploit the `name path` key from the `intersections` library so the paths only have to be specified once, and then do a bunch of clipping...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\tikzset{use path/.code={
  \pgfextra{\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@#1\endcsname}%
}, 
square/.pic={code={
  \path  [pic actions, name path=square #1] 
    (-#1/2,-#1/2) rectangle ++(#1,#1);
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1em]
\pic [fill=gray,  rotate=45]  at (0,0)   {square=11};
\pic [fill=black, rotate=-30] at (7,0)   {square=9};
\pic [fill=gray,  rotate=10]  at (14,-2) {square=7};
\pic [fill=black, rotate=30]  at (18,-5) {square=5};

\foreach \l/\r in {11/9, 9/7, 7/5}{
\begin{scope}
  \clip [use path=square \l]; \clip [use path=square \r];
  \fill [use path=square \l, white];
\end{scope}}
\foreach \s in {5, 7, 9, 11} \draw [use path=square \s];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Here is one possible solution that draws the gray rectangles, then draw the black rectangles and redraw inside (clipping is done by `path picture`) the first two rectangles in white.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % the two gray rectangles
    \node[draw, fill=gray, minimum size=4cm, rotate=45] (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node[draw, fill=gray, minimum size=2cm, rotate=20] (C) at (5,.5) {};
    % the two black rectangles and the white rectangles clipped inside
    \node[draw, fill=black, minimum size=3cm, rotate=-20,
      path picture={
        \node[draw, fill=white, minimum size=4cm, rotate=45] at (A) {};
        \node[draw, fill=white, minimum size=2cm, rotate=20] at (C) {};
      }] at (3,1){};
    \node[draw, fill=black, minimum size=1cm, rotate=30,
      path picture={
        \node[draw, fill=white, minimum size=2cm, rotate=20] at (C) {};
      }] (D) at (6.2,0) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** Please the next time add a MWE in your question.

Answer (score 5):

A low-complexity approach is to use two paths for clipping the white areas in the black rectangles. Here, we simply construct the four rectangles (A), (B), (C), (D) with arguments: `[minimum size=#1,rotate=#2,fill=#3]`. Then, we set a path the same as `node(A)` by:

```
\path[clip] (A.45)--(A.135)--(A.-135)--(A.-45)--cycle;
```

because a node cannot be used for clipping. This is used to construct the white area in rectangle (B). Next, we set a path the same as `node(C)` by:

```
\path[clip] (C.45)--(C.135)--(C.-135)--(C.-45)--cycle;
```

and use it for clipping the remaining two white areas in rectangles (B) and (D).

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blk/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{draw,minimum size=#1,rotate=#2,fill=#3}] 

\node(A)[blk={4cm,45,gray}]at(0,0){};
\node(B)[blk={3cm,70,black}]at(3,1){};
\node(C)[blk={2cm,20,gray}]at(5,.5){};
\node(D)[blk={1cm,30,black}]at(6.2,0){};

\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (A.45)--(A.135)--(A.-135)--(A.-45)--cycle;
\node[blk={3cm,70,white}]at(3,1){};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (C.45)--(C.135)--(C.-135)--(C.-45)--cycle;
\node[blk={3cm,70,white}]at(3,1){};
\node[blk={1cm,30,white}]at(6.2,0){};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it).

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

u := 1.6mm;
defaultfont := "phvr8r";
path A, B, C, D;

A = unitsquare scaled  5u rotated  30;
B = unitsquare scaled  7u rotated  20 shifted (-6u,1u);
C = unitsquare scaled  9u rotated  80 shifted (-7u,1u);
D = unitsquare scaled 11u rotated  50 shifted (-18u,-3u);


fill A withcolor .3 white; 
fill B withcolor .8 white;
fill C withcolor .3 white;
fill D withcolor .8 white;

unfill buildcycle(A,B);
unfill buildcycle(B,C);
unfill buildcycle(C,D);

draw A; draw B; draw C; draw D;

label.urt("5", point 1.5 of A);
label.bot("7", point 0.3 of B);
label.top("9", point 1.5 of C);
label.ulft("11", point 2.5 of D);

endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Note that if the start (`point 0 of ...`) of any of the squares falls inside any of the others, then `buildcycle` fails to find the correct overlap for the reasons explained in my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155395/why-two-intersected-paths-cant-buildcycle-in-metapost/236226#236226).