# Generate all 16 possible 2-variable shaded Venn diagrams in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikzscale, venn-diagrams

Let `P` and `Q` be two statements, each with 2 possible truth values: true (`T`) or false (`F`). These component statements `P` and `Q` can be joined by 16 possible binary connectives to form [16 unique simple compound statements](http://finitegeometry.org/sc/16/logic.html), each of which can be illustrated with Venn diagrams (see previous link).

I have seen several solutions given [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex) for generating a Venn diagram, however none of these seems to be easily tweaked to get the other 15 out of 16 cases. Actually, my question is essentially the 2-variable version of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67395/how-to-generate-all-possible-venn-diagrams-with-the-case-below-efficiently).

**The solution I'm looking for**:

Ideally, you could get the TikZ figure you want by typing

- `TTTT` to shade all 4 regions
- `FFFF` to shade no regions
- `FTTT` to shade all regions except the intersection
- `TFFF` to shade only the intersection
- `TTFF` to shade only the left circle
- `FFTT` to shade the complement of the left circle
- etc...

Is there a TikZ algorithm that could generate any one of the 16 possible Venn diagrams with a simple tweak in the code like this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you just want the images I have uploaded them all here: https://github.com/Ace-Cassidy/Venn-Diagram-Pictures

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No clipping or even-odd-rule required:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone} 
\tikzset{%
  v 0/.style={fill=white}, v 1/.style={fill=blue!30},
  pics/venn/.style args={#1#2#3#4}{code={%
    \fill [v #1/.try] (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,1.5);
    \fill [v #2/.try] (90:sin 60) arc (120:-120:1) arc (-60:60:1);
    \fill [v #3/.try] (90:sin 60) arc (60:300:1)   arc (240:120:1);
    \fill [v #4/.try] (90:sin 60) arc (120:240:1)  arc (-60:60:1);
    \draw (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,1.5)
      (90:sin 60) arc (120:-120:1) arc (-60:60:1)
      arc (60:300:1) arc (240:120:1) -- cycle;
}}}
\pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{4}% <- Very important!
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1em]
\foreach \i in {0,...,15}{
  \pgfmathdectobase\n{\i}{2}
  \pic at ({mod(\i, 4)*6}, {-floor(\i/4)*4}) {venn/.expanded=\n};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This could be applied as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz,array,centernot,amsmath,mathrsfs}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2em}
\tikzset{%
  v 0/.style={fill=white}, v 1/.style={fill=blue!30},
  pics/venn/.style args={#1#2#3#4}{code={%
    \fill [v #4/.try] (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,1.5);
    \fill [v #3/.try] (90:sin 60) arc (120:-120:1) arc (-60:60:1);
    \fill [v #2/.try] (90:sin 60) arc (60:300:1)   arc (240:120:1);
    \fill [v #1/.try] (90:sin 60) arc (120:240:1)  arc (-60:60:1);
    \draw (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,1.5)
      (90:sin 60) arc (120:-120:1) arc (-60:60:1)
      arc (60:300:1) arc (240:120:1) -- cycle;
}}}
\newcommand\venn[2][]{{\tikz[every venn/.try, #1]\pic{venn/.expanded=#2};}}
\tikzset{every venn/.style={x=1em, y=1em, baseline=-.666ex, 
  v 1/.style={fill=gray}}}
\begin{document} 
$\displaystyle
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Truth Table} & \textrm{Venn Diagram} & \textrm{Connective} & \textrm{Connective Name} \\
\hline
FFFF & \venn{0000} & \mathscr{P} \perp \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Contradiction} \\
FFFT & \venn{0001} & \mathscr{P} \overline{\lor} \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Nondisjunction (Nor)} \\
FFTF & \venn{0010} & \mathscr{P} \centernot\impliedby \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Converse Nonimplication} \\[2em]
\hline
\end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's a 3-variable version:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone} 
\tikzset{v 0/.style={fill=white}, v 1/.style={fill=blue!30},
   venn path 1/.style={insert path={ 
     (90:1/sqrt 3) arc (60:120:1) arc (180:0:1) arc (60:120:1) -- cycle }},
   venn path 2/.style={insert path={ 
     (90:1/sqrt 3) arc (120:180:1) arc (240:180:1) arc (120:60:1) -- cycle }},
   venn path 3/.style={insert path={ 
     (90:1/sqrt 3) arc (120:180:1) arc (240:300:1) arc (0:60:1) -- cycle }},
   pics/venn 3/.style args={#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8}{code={%
     \fill [v #1] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
     \fill [v #2, rotate=240, venn path 1]; 
     \fill [v #3, rotate=120, venn path 1];  
     \fill [v #4, venn path 1];  
     \fill [v #5, rotate=240, venn path 2];  
     \fill [v #6, rotate=120, venn path 2];  
     \fill [v #7, venn path 2];  
     \fill [v #8, venn path 3];
     \draw (90:1/sqrt 3) circle [radius=1] (210:1/sqrt 3) circle [radius=1]
       (330:1/sqrt 3) circle [radius=1] (-2, -2) rectangle (2,2);
}}}
\pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{8}% Still very important!
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1em]
\foreach \i in {0,...,255}{
  \pgfmathdectobase\n{\i}{2}
  \pic at ({mod(\i, 16)*4}, {-floor(\i/16)*4}) {venn 3/.expanded=\n};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Truly beautiful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark - I love it. If I want to call a specific one of the set, e.g. type `\venn{TTFF}` to output one with only the left circle shaded, how can I do that?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree `\newcommand\venn[2][]{{\pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{4}\tikz[#1]\pic{venn/.expanded=#2};}}` should do it. Then use `\venn{0011}`. Note, that the argument is`0011` not `1100` (it made more sense to me when thinking in binary), and the `\venn` command puts each diagram in a separate `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Is there any way I can let `1100` be the left circle and `1010` be the right circle?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree just reverse the order of the arguments in the fill commands where it says `[v #1/.try]`. Currently, the sequence goes (line by line) from  `v #1` to `v #4`. Just do it the other way around.

Comment: Thanks again Mark. One last question: does this approach allow for `scale` and `baseline` options? I need these diagrams to fit in a table array like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266386/vertically-center-elements-in-rows-of-array/

Comment: @EthanAlvaree the definition of `\venn` given above includes an optional argument which is passed to the `\tikz` command. So you can say `\venn[x=1em, y=1em, baseline=0]{1100}`. Alternatively you could redefine `\venn` and change `\tikz[#1]` to `\tikz[every venn/.try,#1]`. Then you could set scale and baseline options in the document preamble and not have to specify them every time you use `\venn`. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Hi! Can anybody help me to set \ven command for 3-sets case? It would be great to use commands like \venn{00000001}.

Comment: The second question is how should we modify the code to get a picture with the central circle under two other circles?

Comment: Can that last one be done with the relevant expressions (i.e. **A⋂B⋃C'**) underneath/inside the squares; or would you have to go through and do them all manually, one by one?

Comment: @tjtube263 with the current implementation no. The current mapping between the binary representation and the corresponding shaded regions  is arbitrary and would require some (i.e., a lot) of work to map the representation on to the relevant set-expressions

Answer (score 17):

Well you can just remove the `(C)` and you are done

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\venn@strip#1#2\venn@STOP{\def\venn@next{#1}\gdef\venn@rest{#2}}

\newcommand{\venn}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (S-SE) at (5,-3);
\coordinate (S-NW) at (-3,{sqrt(3)+3});
  \edef\venn@rest{#10000}%
  \foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
  \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
    \expandafter\venn@strip\venn@rest\venn@STOP
    \ifnum\venn@next=1\relax
    \pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,2) == 1 ? "(S-SE) rectangle (S-NW)" : ""}
    \path[clip] \pgfmathresult (A) circle[radius=2];
    \pgfmathparse{Mod(floor(\i/2),2) == 1 ? "(S-SE) rectangle (S-NW)" : ""}
    \path[clip] \pgfmathresult (B) circle[radius=2];
    \pgfmathparse{Mod(floor(\i/4),2) == 1 ? "(S-SE) rectangle (S-NW)" : ""}
    \fill[rounded corners,red] (S-SE) rectangle (S-NW);
    \fi
  \end{scope}
  }
    \draw[ultra thick] (A) circle[radius=2];
    \draw[ultra thick] (B) circle[radius=2];
    \draw[ultra thick,rounded corners] (S-SE) rectangle (S-NW);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\allvendiagrams}{%
\foreach \j in {0,...,15} {%
  \def\venncode{}%
  \foreach \k in {0,...,3} {%
    \pgfmathparse{Mod(floor(\j/2^\k),2) == 1 ? "\venncode1" : "\venncode0"}%
    \global\let\venncode=\pgfmathresult%
  }
  \venn{\venncode}%
}\par%
}


\begin{document}
\venn{1000}
\venn{0100}
\venn{1100}
\allvendiagrams
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Percusse, thanks for your answer! Do you know how we can make the circles fit the square better? Right now I think the figure is still designed for 3 circles instead of 2, which is why the circles aren't taking up the entire square.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree Change the location of North west coordinate a little lower

Comment: Hi Percusse, changing the value to sqrt(3)+1.5 seems to work. One more question: the code seems to have the circles backward. That is, it thinks TTFF is the right circle (but it should be left), and it thinks TFTF is the left circle (but it should be right). How can I fix this?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree Mark Wibrow's answer is more tempting so I would recommend using that one, though I'll check if this is salvagable too later when I have time. The solution is to change the order of the clipping etc. to reverse the arguments.

Answer (score 14):

The areas in the diagrams are drawn with a combination of clip and fill commands. Each bit position encodes one of the four intersection free areas of the diagram. These areas are drawn independently.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\w{1.35}
  \def\h{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\rad{\h*.35}
  \def\sep{.2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Ax{\h/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Bx{\w - \h/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\My{\h/2}
  \def\vennfill 1#1#2#3#4{%
    \begin{scope}[radius=\rad, even odd rule]
      \ifnum#1=1 %
        \begin{scope}
          \clip
            (0, 0) rectangle (\w, \h)
            (\Ax, \My) circle[]
          ;
          \clip
            (0, 0) rectangle (\w, \h)
            (\Bx, \My) circle[]
          ;
          \fill
            (0, 0) rectangle (\w, \h)
          ;
        \end{scope}
      \fi
      \ifnum#2=1 %
        \begin{scope}
          \clip
            (\Bx, \My) circle[]
          ;
          \fill[even odd rule]
            (\Ax, \My) circle[]
            (\Bx, \My) circle[]
          ;
        \end{scope}
      \fi
      \ifnum#3=1 %
        \begin{scope}
          \clip (\Ax, \My) circle[];
          \fill[even odd rule]
            (\Ax, \My) circle[]
            (\Bx, \My) circle[]
          ;
        \end{scope}
      \fi
      \ifnum#4=1 %
        \clip (\Ax, \My) circle[];
        \clip (\Bx, \My) circle[];
        \fill (\Ax, \My) circle[];
      \fi
    \end{scope}
  }%
  \path[
    venn/.pic={
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\vennfill\tikzpictext
      \draw[radius=\rad]
        (0, 0) rectangle (\w, \h)
        (\h/2, \h/2) circle[]
        (\w-\h/2, \h/2) circle[]
      ;
    }
  ]
    \foreach \r in {0, ..., 3} {
      \foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \bin using bin(\r*4+\c+16)] in {0, ..., 3} {
        (\c*\w + \c*\sep, -\r*\h - \r*\sep)
        pic[fill=red, pic text=\bin] {venn}
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 13):

And here's a version in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) for comparison.  This exploits a feature of `buildcycle` with two circular paths that was discussed in my answer to [this quesion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155395/why-two-intersected-paths-cant-buildcycle-in-metapost).

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

color venn_color; venn_color = 0.8[blue,white];
vardef venn(expr p, q, r, s) =
  save a, b, c, d, f, u; path a,b,c,d, f[]; u = 1cm;
  f1 = fullcircle scaled 1u shifted -(1/4u,0);
  f2 = fullcircle scaled 1u shifted +(1/4u,0);
  a = buildcycle(reverse f1, f2);
  b = buildcycle(f1 rotatedabout(center f1, 180), f2);
  c = a rotated 180;
  d = unitsquare shifted -(1/2,1/2) xscaled 2u yscaled 1.414u;
  image(unfill d; if p=1: fill d withcolor venn_color;
  unfill a; unfill b; unfill c; fi
  if q=1: fill a withcolor venn_color; fi
  if r=1: fill b withcolor venn_color; fi
  if s=1: fill c withcolor venn_color; fi
  draw a; draw c; draw d;)
enddef;

beginfig(1);
  for i=0 upto 1: for j=0 upto 1: for k=0 upto 1: for l=0 upto 1:
    x0 := 180i+90j; y0 := 120k+60l;
    draw venn(i,j,k,l) shifted z0;
    label(decimal i & decimal j & decimal k & decimal l, z0 shifted 27 down);
  endfor; endfor; endfor; endfor;
endfig;


end.
```

[image]