# MetaPost: My code with buildcycle doesn't have the correct output and nothing changes

Tags: metapost

```
beginfig(1)
input hatching;
      u := 5 mm;
      path xtelg,ytelg;
  xtelg := (-4u,0) -- (6u,0);
  ytelg := (0,-4u) -- (0,9u);
  drawarrow xtelg;
  drawarrow ytelg;
  path parab, paraa,m,n,kujund;
  parab:= (0u,8u) for i=0.5 step .5 until 6: .. (i*u, (i*i-6*i+8)*u) endfor;
  paraa:= (-3u,5u) for i=-2 step .5 until 3: ..(i*u,(i*i-4)*u) endfor;
  draw parab;
  draw paraa;
  m:=(0,-4u)--(0,8u) for i=0 step 0.5 until 2: ..(i*u,(i**2-6*i+8)*u) endfor;
  n:=(0,-4u) for i=0 step 0.5 until 2: ..(i*u,(i**2-4)*u) endfor;
  kujund:=buildcycle(m,n);
  hatchfill kujund withcolor(45,1mm,.5bp);
  draw kujund;
endfig;
end
```

Like I mentioned above, I don't know why the hatchfill won't fill my graph.

Comment: This is your 3rd question and you did not accept the provided answer. Do you shoudl accept an answer, if it solved your problem?

Comment: "Do you shoudl" = "Do you know, that you should"

Comment: You might also like to review the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155395/15036)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
kujund:=buildcycle(m, n);
```

try

```
kujund:=buildcycle(reverse m, n);
```

or

```
kujund:=buildcycle(m, reverse n);
```

Either way, it works for me:

[image]

By the way, the `buildcycle` macro can be tricky if used with only two paths. See the [Metapost documentation](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) p. 30-32 for more details about how it works. Given this way of working, it seems that by asking

```
buildcycle(m,n)
```

it leads Metapost to build a cycle between either only two points (I guess (0,-4) and the intersection of the two parabolas) or even only one point (I suppose (0,-4)) hence the absence of apparent result. Whereas

```
buildcycle(m, reverse n)
```

leads it to build the requested cycle between the expected intersection points.

Comment: note that if you really want hatching, you need to make the third components of the "color" negative.  The fill is coming out as pale yellow here because the color `(45, 1mm, 0.5bp)` is being interepreted as `(1, 1, 0.5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly simpler version that gets rid of the temporary paths `m` and `n`, and uses the *y*-axis directly in the `buildcycle` command (which also gets rid of the need to reverse one of the paths).

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

input hatching

beginfig(1);
    numeric u;
    u = 5 mm;

    path xtelg,ytelg;
    xtelg = (4 left -- 6 right) scaled u;
    ytelg = (4 down -- 9 up) scaled u;

    path parab, paraa, kujund;
    parab = ((0, 8) for i=1/2 step 1/2 until 6: .. (i, i**2 - 6i + 8) endfor) scaled u;
    paraa = ((-3, 5) for i=-2 step 1/2 until 3: .. (i, i**2 - 4) endfor) scaled u;

    kujund = buildcycle(ytelg, parab, paraa);

    drawoptions(withcolor 1/2 white);
    hatchfill kujund withcolor (45, 3, -1/2);
    drawoptions();

    draw parab;
    draw paraa;
    drawarrow xtelg;
    drawarrow ytelg;

endfig;
end.
```

[image]